# What's a good practice to manage resources, especially images

Tags: java, image, resources

I am working with Java2d at the moment and trying to figure out a good way to load and store images I paint on the screen. Usually I use an ImageLoader I wrote a long way back which stores all loaded images by their location as key in a hash map. My problem now is that after loading a lot of images the application tends to use a large amount of memory.

It is logical because for one animation of a toon i already have a tile map with the size of 1248 x 4928, which according to my calculation is about 62Mb in memory. Loading several of those toons would very quickly fill up the memory, and I haven't even loaded any world objects yet.

Is there a better way to handle image resources?

I tried with VolatileImage already but even though they should be stored inside GPU memory they still eat up a lot of the system memory as well. Also loading image files on the fly when needed probably would slow the whole paint loop down seriously because of all the disc access.

Comment: *"...  **propably** would slow the whole paint loop down  ..."* have you tried this to see if what you **think** is actually a **fact**?

Comment: Yes, i tested it partly allready. The framerate droped a bit even with only a few loading operations in the loop. The other downside of this approach is that you should never create larger objects inside a paintloop, if any at all. A painloop usualy is called several times a second, and creating new objects for every run will increase the memory usage even more, because the garbage collector wont be able to keep up with the discarded objects.